# Multimeter not showing same current as bench power supply

Tags: power-supply, current, current-measurement, multimeter

I’m getting a different reading on my multimeter for current than what shows on my bench power supply.

The bench power supply shows 5 mA. This makes sense with the displayed volts and watts- 2V*.005A=.010W

[image: bench power supply display]

The multimeter shows 11.58 mA.

[image: multimeter]

The multimeter is older than the bench power supply. I’ve heard that you can break the multimeter by using the current setting incorrectly, something that I could have done in the past unknowingly.

What could cause this discrepancy? Does it look like I broke my multimeter? If so is it possible to fix it easily?

Comment: Probably just measurement error.

Comment: A very low battery can cause problems with multimeter readings; that would be my first line of investigation personally.

Comment: do a simple load measurement test with something simple like a known resistor (like 12V, 1.2kohm should sink 10mA). Also if the load is not DC (like it has pulses or such) an average meter and a true rms meter will give different answers. Or maybe one or both of the instruments are out of calibration

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's probably a bit of offset in the amplifier for the current measurement. You should believe the DVM before the power supply current or wattage display.

You can't expect metrology-lab measurements from the display on a $99 programmable power supply. The display has 0.1% F.S. error at that point. The power is no doubt simply calculated from the voltage and measured current. They may have biased it that way to prevent the more disturbing display of current when there is none.

I would expect it to be more accurate as you get into the hundreds of mA to A. You can verify by increasing the voltage slowly from zero, you will likely see the power supply current display read zero until the DVM is reading around 5mA, then it will go up 1mA for every 1mA.

Even inexpensive DVMs tend to have a very good auto-zero strategy and will always read close to 0 with 0 in. Inexpensive ones may have poor span accuracy so the reading will diverge from true the higher you go away from zero.

Comment: I think this is what it is. I tried what you suggested. My power supply showed 0 until I hit 10 mA on my DVM. Then I tried increasing the current from the power supply by increasing the voltage and raising the current limit. This lead to the dvm readings to get closer to the power supply readings the higher the current

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to check the fuse in your DMM.  If the fuse has been replaced at some point by the wrong size, then the mA reading wont be accurate.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE, Simon. You'd need to explain why you think that is the case. In fact the fuse will come before the measurement shunt and the mA reading is generated by the voltage drop across the shunt only - not the combination of fuse and shunt. That means that the fuse will not introduce an error into the current reading. Since the PSU and meter are **in series** the same current must be flowing in both so, theoretically, there should be no error. That's what prompted the original question. You can [edit] your answer at any time to improve it.

Comment: You do not show the actual hookup but the meters have different sense devices and typically measure a voltage drop across them. Put the meters in series and see what you get.  This is based on: Kirchhoff's current law (1st Law) states that the current flowing into a node (or a junction) must be equal to the current flowing out of it. This is a consequence of charge conservation.  If you have a resistor you can put that in series and measure the voltage drop across it but you will also get tolerance stacking on the resistor and volt meter.